# Ace editor with Vim mode and Emmet enabled

Tags: vim, ace-editor, emmet

I am trying to use the ace editor with Vim Keybindings and Emmet enabled for html editing.

It seems that when using Vim mode, the emmet extension gets disabled.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Abesproject/67BL6/2/) exposing the issue.

```
ace.require("ace/ext/emmet");

var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setKeyboardHandler('ace/keyboard/vim');
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.setOption("enableEmmet", true);
```

Anyone knows if this is expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Use `editor.setOption("enableEmmet", true);` above set mode